# Python calling an SDK function in DLL of a sensor that takes pointer IP and port and return a void* (void* a handle to the profile sensor.)

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I am just new in Python. I am trying to connect to a laser sensor through its DLL library. The SDK functions in this Library are compiled in C++ language.

By using ctypes in python my first try is to call the EthernetScanner_Connect function. The function parameters are as follow:

```
void* EthernetScanner_Connect(char *chIP, char *chPort, int iTimeOut)
```

According to the function discription in c++ it should return NULL pointer if a failure in connection occurs, otherwise it should return the handle to the profile sensor, which is gonna be used in other functions.

My code on python untill now:

```
from ctypes import *

lib=windll.LoadLibrary("c:\\EthernetScanner.dll")

if lib:
    print("the Library is loaded")

EthernetScanner_Connect = getattr(lib,"EthernetScanner_Connect")

EthernetScanner_Connect.restype = c_void_p
EthernetScanner_Connect.argtypes =[c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int]
x = EthernetScanner_Connect(b"193.164.200.1\0",b"32407\0",0)

print(x)
```

while I am expecting NULL from this function because i am not connected to the sensor yet, it is giving me the following:

```
the Library is loaded
45940800
```

Comment: Hmm, it appears that the function was able to connect to that *IP*/port. What happens if you use that value in other functions?

Comment: I tried to use it with a function that check the connection and it tured a 0 value. a 0 value mean that the sensor is disconnected(which is true) or the given IP or Port are not valid. I am not sure for what reason does the other function return 0

Comment: Well (I can only guess here), seems like something is listening on that *IP* / port, and the connection succeeds, but apparently it's not a sensor (that's why other functions fail).

Comment: how to check if something else is listening to my IP Port

Comment: The most straightforward way would be using `socket.create_connection`. But I'm not sure what protocol does it use. Also, you don't need to manually add `\0` at the end of the strings. Is it possible to share the function documentation, and the *.dll*?

Comment: I found smth: http://www.sensores-de-medida.es/uploads/hb-m2-ilan-udp-e.pdf. Try *EthernetScanner\_GetConnectStatus* or *EthernetScanner\_Disconnect* on the pointer. Also, when connecting, try a value different than 0 for *timeout*).

Comment: Thanks alot this sensor is the same as the sensor I am working with. the Idea is that I do have the dll file and a pdf file that describes the usage of SDK functions in the DLL. I tried EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus and its giving me (0) while connected to the sensor. this means it couldn't connect

Comment: Hmm, I knew something didn't quite fit.... you changed your user name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start by pointing out [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

I'm going to post an answer based on some assumptions:

1. The sensor you're talking about is the same one as described in [[FoxControls]: acuity-ap820-users-manual.pdf](https://www.foxcontrols.co.za/download/files/product_uploads/acuity-ap820-users-manual.pdf). If this isn't true, the answer is useless
2. According to above doc, *EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus*'s possible return statuses are (**emphasis** is mine):

   > Status is a unsigned integer used as a buffer to contain the status code when the
   >   function returns.
   > The status codes are:
   >
   > - 0: Disconnected
   > - 1: Disconnecting
   > - 2: **Connecting**
   > - 3: Connected

   Based on the above, and the fact that the connect timeout is 0, I assumed (**nothing in the *doc* to support it**, though) that it tries to connect in **non blocking** mode:

   - *EthernetScanner_Connect* returns **immediately** (meaning that **before** attempting to connect - it "schedules" a connection operation if you will) a **non *NULL*** pointer. For a *non blocking* (*async*) *IO* example, check [[MS.Docs]: connect function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect)
   - The (above) pointer should be queried (periodically) using *EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus*. That's why it makes sense for the pointer to be non *NULL* (as when *EthernetScanner_Connect* returns, the connection attempt result is not yet known)

Here's a piece of code that is supposed to deal with the problem (needless to say that it's *blind coding* - meaning that I didn't actually test it). 
As a consequence of the 2<sup>nd</sup> assumption, if passing a timeout **greater than 0**, *EthernetScanner_Connect* **should** return *NULL*.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes
import time


DLL_NAME = "c:\\EthernetScanner.dll"

CONNECT_STATUS_DISCONNECTED = 0
CONNECT_STATUS_DISCONNECTING = 1
CONNECT_STATUS_CONNECTING = 2
CONNECT_STATUS_CONNECTED = 3

CONNECT_STATUSES_PENDING = [
    CONNECT_STATUS_CONNECTING,
    CONNECT_STATUS_DISCONNECTING,
]

def main():

    connect_timeout_msec = 0
    nb_mode = connect_timeout_msec == 0

    dll = ctypes.WinDLL(DLL_NAME)

    EthernetScanner_Connect = dll.EthernetScanner_Connect
    EthernetScanner_Connect.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_uint32]
    EthernetScanner_Connect.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

    EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus = dll.EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus
    EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)]

    EthernetScanner_Disconnect = dll.EthernetScanner_Disconnect
    EthernetScanner_Disconnect.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
    EthernetScanner_Disconnect.restype = ctypes.c_uint32

    ptr = EthernetScanner_Connect(b"192.168.100.1", b"32001", connect_timeout_msec)
    if nb_mode:
        print("Non blocking mode: EthernetScanner_Connect returned {:}".format(ptr))
        poll_timeout_sec = 0.5
        connect_status = ctypes.c_int(CONNECT_STATUS_CONNECTING)
        while connect_status.value in CONNECT_STATUSES_PENDING:
            time.sleep(poll_timeout_sec)
            EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus(ptr, ctypes.byref(connect_status))
        if connect_status.value != CONNECT_STATUS_CONNECTED:
            print("Couldn't connect (status: {:})!".format(connect_status.value))
            return
    else:
        print("Blocking mode: EthernetScanner_Connect returned {:}".format(ptr))
        if not ptr:
            print("Couldn't connect!")
            return

    # Do something with the sensor (pointer)

    EthernetScanner_Disconnect(ptr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("Done.")
```

Comment: CristiFati.... Big Thanks for this effort, I will try to go through this all, right now.

Comment: the function EthernetScanner_GetConnectStatus is a non blocking function as defined in the description document

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with the question / answer?

Comment: I am making it clear that this function is a non blocking function as stated in the sensor SDK function description. It is actually still giving me back an integer. I tried to comple your code and the ptr value according to  this `ptr = EthernetScanner_Connect(b"192.168.100.1", b"32001", connect_timeout_msec)`  is 45219904

Comment: Ok, it's implicit that *EthernetScanner\_GetConnectStatus* it is non blocking. But anyway I don't see how is that relevant, I never stated that it wouldn't be so. Yes it's normal to have a non *NULL* pointer.

Comment: Now I understand your point of view. But in my list discription its states that the `EthernetScanner_Connect` will return Null if failure(failure of connecting to the sensor).

Comment: and that is exactly what i am waiting to have because i am not connected to the sensor with the ethernet cable.

Comment: I see that you're having a hard time understanding non blocking IO. I updated the answer. In short when *EthernetScanner\_Connect* returns it doesn't know whether the connection attempt succeeded or failed (it tries to connect in the "background"), so that;s why it's OK to have anon null pointer (to be queried afterwards).

Comment: your code worked! Thank you one more time. Can you please explain to me why did you use the while loop and sleep time function? how did this solved the problem ? I looked in the connect function linke example, it didn't use the sleep time function that you used

Comment: You're welcome! I did it because when *EthernetScanner\_Connect* returned, it didn't try connect. So I had to wait until it tries to connect (in the backend), and go on only after it succeeds or fails.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark the answer as a solution to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that you marked it as a solution (you didn't vote for it). By contact, you mean outside SO?.

Comment: fati_utcluj@yahoo.com.