# calling a function which supposed to return None through ctype and it is returning integer

Tags: python

I am writing a ctypes code to call function from a DLL. one of the function is the connect function for a sensor. This function should return the Handler to the sensor(void*) but in case of failure it should return Null.

The function take an IP and Port to connect to the sensor. The problem is that it keeps returning integer like(45940800) which change every execution. Whatever the input IP or Port the integer is always returned. What is this integer? is the handler or the pointer to profile sensor? why is the function not showing the NULL pointer while i am totally not connected to the sensor?

```
from ctypes import*


lib=windll.LoadLibrary("c:\\weCat3D\\weCat3D\\EthernetScanner\\EthernetScanner")
EthernetScanner_Connect = lib.EthernetScanner_Connect
EthernetScanner_Connect.restype=c_void_p
EthernetScanner_Connect.argtypes =[c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int]
x=EthernetScanner_Connect(b'192.168.100.1',b'32001\0',0)
print(x)


The function takes an IP and Port to connect to a sensor. The problem is that it keeps returning integer like(45940800) which change every time i run. Whatever the input IP or Port the integer is always returned. What is this integer? is it the handler or the pointer to profile sensor? why is the function not showing the NULL pointer while i am totally not connected to the sensor?
```

Comment: Why did you open a new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863680/python-calling-an-sdk-function-in-dll-of-a-sensor-that-takes-pointer-ip-and-port.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to understand the out put of the function, I mean this integer number is appearing whatever I do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python calling an SDK function in DLL of a sensor that takes pointer IP and port and return a void\* (void\* a handle to the profile sensor.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863680/python-calling-an-sdk-function-in-dll-of-a-sensor-that-takes-pointer-ip-and-port)